# Jquery : Changing the last div's content id without reflecting changes to previous one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one div who's id is `xyz1` and inside it i has 3 div who's id is `abc1`,`def1`,`ghi1` respectfully. 
When user click on `ADD NEW` button the current div `xyz1` should get cloned and get hidden and the cloned div get appended to below `xyz1` div . And the new cloned div will be having parent id `xyz2` and their children div's should have id `abc2`,`def2`,`ghi2`.
Following code should make more sense .

```
<div id="xyz1" style="display:block">
     <div id="abc1" class="abc"></div>
     <div id="def1" class="def"></div>
     <div id="ghi1" class="ghi"></div>
</div>
```

When user click on `ADD NEW` button this div should get hide and the next div should be like below .

```
<div id="xyz2" style="display:block">
     <div id="abc2" class="abc"></div>
     <div id="def2" class="def"></div>
     <div id="ghi2" class="ghi"></div>
</div>
```

**IMPORTANT:** Previous div's id number should not get modified .

What i did

```
var $cloned_div = $("#xyz1").clone().prop("id","xyz2");
$($cloned_div).appendTo("div:last");
$("#xyz2").each(function(){
   $(".abc").prop("id","abc2");
   $(".def").prop("id","def2");
   $(".ghi").prop("id","ghi2");
});
```

This is working fine for second div , but `prop()` method is getting applied to previous one also. Means previous div's id get reflected too.

This is how it becomes

```
<div id="xyz1" style="display:block">
     <div id="abc2" class="abc"></div>
     <div id="def2" class="def"></div>
     <div id="ghi2" class="ghi"></div>
</div>
<div id="xyz2" style="display:block">
     <div id="abc2" class="abc"></div>
     <div id="def2" class="def"></div>
     <div id="ghi2" class="ghi"></div>
</div>
```

And i don't want to change the class name because many dependencies are their in my code for class .

Comment: So what have you tired?

Comment: Where's the JS/jQ? If you ever get around to posting it do it in a [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You're expected to try to **write the code yourself**.If you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you html always last div is visible and you can select it by jQuery [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector. After finding visible div, you should get index of id of it that regex can do this work. When you find last div and index it index, copy it using `.clone()` and change id attribute of cloned elements. At the end, insert copied element after last div by [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) and hide old div.

```
$("button").click(function(){
  // selecte the only div that is visible
  var div = $("[id^='xyz']:visible");
  // get id of target div
  var id = parseInt(div.attr("id").match(/\d+/))+1;
  // copy target div and change id of it and it childs and insert new div after old div.
  div.clone().attr("id", "xyz"+ id)
     .find(".abc").attr("id", "abc"+ id).end()
     .find(".def").attr("id", "def"+ id).end()
     .find(".ghi").attr("id", "ghi"+ id).end()
     .insertAfter(div);
  // hide target div
  div.hide();
});
```

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  var div = $("[id^='xyz']:visible");
  var id = parseInt(div.attr("id").match(/\d+/))+1;
  div.clone().attr("id", "xyz"+ id)
     .find(".abc").attr("id", "abc"+ id).end()
     .find(".def").attr("id", "def"+ id).end()
     .find(".ghi").attr("id", "ghi"+ id).end()
     .insertAfter(div);
  div.hide();
  console.log($("[id^='xyz']:visible")[0].outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>ADD NEW</button>
<div id="xyz1" style="display:block">
  <div id="abc1" class="abc"></div>
  <div id="def1" class="def"></div>
  <div id="ghi1" class="ghi"></div>
</div>
```